# Dismissing a UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

I'm dismissing my UIImagePicker using:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!)
     {
      picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
     }
```

Unfortunately this is also dismissing the view underneath. I don't want this to happen.

I've loaded the UIImagePicker like so:

```
let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()


 @IBAction func uploadFromAlbumButton(sender : UIButton){
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = self
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The view underneath the UIImagePicker gets shown like this:

```
let newViewController = FulfilWishViewController();
newViewController.delegate = self
navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Could you please tell us how you show the view underneath ImagePicker?

Comment: So you have SomeParentViewController, that shows FulfilWishViewController. Then FulfilWishViewController calls ImagePicker. When ImagePicker calls imagePickerControllerDidCancel, it dismisses itself **and** FulfilWishViewController. So you have only SomeParentViewController shown.
Right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I however want it to stay on FulfilWishViewController instead of going back to the SomeParentViewController

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you did any code in viewwillappear(). Because after dismissed UIImagepickerController , it call viewwillappear() of parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you should have the next structure:
[image: Storyboard]
Also, SecondViewController should have storyboard ID
[image]

Your ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapBtn1(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift :

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapBtn2(sender: AnyObject) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This code was tested. I think, the problem is in calling SecondViewController.

**UPDATE:**

If you are using xib, so you call the SecondViewcontroller via:

```
@IBAction func didTapBtn1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

in your ParentViewController

Comment: Thanks for the well worked out explanation. I however am not using Storyboard. I'm using separate .Xib files. How do I go about this instantiating problem in that case?

Comment: No unfortunately this doesn't change the way the cancel button on UIImagePicker responds.

Comment: Perhaps some more information, there is actually one UITabBarController which has 4 items that each become UINavigationControllers when pressed like so: 

let item1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewsFeedViewController(nibName: "NewsFeedView", bundle: nil))